# Why SQL RAND() in select query returns a smaller value than I would like?

Tags: mysql

I have used this line of code many times and it never gave me rows with ID(primary key) greater than 50.I have 134 rows in test table.My goal is the generation range from 0 to 134.I know that SELECT ROUND(RAND()*134) LIMIT 1 gives a perfect result.
In my case, it does not give me a perfect result

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `ID` > (SELECT RAND()*134) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `SELECT ROUND(RAND()*134) AS rnd LIMIT 1;` give perfect results https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=43500855af2e808d556bb72992645a60&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: What do you mean, "it does not give me a perfect result"? This _should_ give you a somewhat random row, including those with ids greater than 50.

Comment: Do I understand you  correctly that you have 134 rows with ID values from 0 to 133, and you want to select one random row from these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need in:

```sql
SELECT test.*
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND()*134) random) rnd
WHERE test.id = rnd.random;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f48d252bce6ff1b68b3e5d6bb6a52455)

Subquery generates one random value within the range, and the row with this `id` value is selected.

---

Why your query cannot work as you need?

```sql
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `ID` > (SELECT RAND()*134) LIMIT 1;
```

The table has 134 rows. For each row **separate** random number is generated (i.e. each separate row has now its own separate random value). Then `id` of each row is compared with the random generated for this row. Of course lower `id` has higher probability to match then the greater. This is the first logical error. Then LIMIT 1 takes all rows matched and return one indefinite (random) row from all matched. This is second logical error of a query.

Comment: Can i get two random rows for example instead 1 ? "SELECT test.*
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND()*134) random) rnd
WHERE test.id > rnd.random LIMIT 2;" gives me the first random row and the second is what is going after first random value and it is not random

Comment: @Welisio Now the subquery generates only one random number. You must generate two (different?) random numbers. Your query will return two rows which will be adjacent with high probability - use your query only if this is safe for you.